# Is there a way to retrieve the properties for a printer without using wmi?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, wmi

I need to retrieve printer properties to check if the printer is ready before executing print process, using WMI but I get erroned values.

Here is my code :

```
ManagementObjectSearcher objectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = objectSearcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject printer in objectCollection)
{
    foreach (PropertyData property in printer.Properties)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " : " + property.Value);
    }
}
```

I get `"PrinterStatus = 3"` and `"PrinterState = 0"`.

And According to [Win32_Printer page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx) :

> If you are retrieving PrinterStatus = 3 or PrinterState = 0, the printer driver may not be feeding accurate information into WMI. WMI retrieves the printer information from the spoolsv.exe process. It is possible the printer driver does not report its status to the spooler. In this case, Win32_Printer reports the printer as Idle.

I've been looking for solving this problem for many days but it looks like there is no solution in this case.

So I am looking for another way to retrieve properties. I heard of SNMP but didn't really find what I was looking for.

Thanks.

UPDATE : So I kind of answered my question but I'm still open to a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Printing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: Maybe ping it to see if it is on the network as a start? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes it is on the network, this is not the problem, the printer is working. I need to get these info in case an error occurs.
I've already tried using System.Printing quickly but it didn't help me that much, I'll take a closer look, thanks

Comment: This may prove interesting for you https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/160129

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the equivalent of what I was looking for, using System.Printing.

```
PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer();
PrintQueue printQueue = printServer.GetPrintQueue("HP USB");

foreach (PropertyInfo property in printQueue.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " : " + property.GetValue(printQueue));
}
```

This way I can check what the printer is doing and if any error occurs.